# PostgreSQL crashing repeatedly

Tags: postgresql

My PostgreSQL DB crashing repeatedly for running only 5-10 min. and below log prints:

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-12-12 09:40:32 PKT
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  server process (PID 10780) exited with exit code 255
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
FATAL:  pre-existing shared memory block is still in use
HINT:  Check if there are any old server processes still running, and terminate them.
```

Tried to restart the JasperreportsPostgreSQL service but it only run for 5-10 min.

Comment: Set `log_line_prefix to `%m [%p] ` so you get the process ID logged. Then you at least know which process died. The question is unanswerable, because you didn't tell us anything about your setup and what you are doing.

Comment: What is this `JasperreportsPostgreSQL` thing? And how does it control/start PostgreSQL? Do you have any non-standard extensions in your instance? Which operating system is this?

Comment: POSTGRESQL DB is running by Jasper Reports server (a reporting tool) on Windows 2016 OS